# Wrap text around pseudocode

Tags: algorithms, wrapfigure

I use `algorithm`/`algorithmic` packages to write some pseudocode. The width of the box spans across the entire page and I was wondering if there is any way to constrain it (since the actual code doesn't exceed the mid of the page). Practically, I want to wrap text around my pseudocode.

ps: I tried `wrapfig` package, but I had some problems. Would be also helpful if anyone could verify whether this approach works.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Don't forget about [tex.se]; LaTeX is odd enough that you'd be better served asking in a community dedicated to LaTeX and TeX. (I've flagged for moderator attention to migrate, but in case the mod doesn't migrate -- we _do_ have LaTeX questions here, in any case -- just know it's available.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from another StackExchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question. `:)`

Answer (score 19):

You can put the `algorithm` inside of a minipage, put that inside of the wrapfigure, and it should work like a charm.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{algorithm}[H]
        \caption{assignment algorithm}
        \begin{algorithmic}
          \STATE i $\leftarrow$ j
        \end{algorithmic}
      \end{algorithm}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{wrapfigure}
  \lipsum
\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image: Wrapped algorithm]

You might want to tweak the alignment modifier on the `minipage` to get vertical alignment to work out a little better. Alternatively, you can play with the optionial `lineheight` of `wrapfigure`.

Comment: Could one modify this to work with Algorithm2e?

Comment: @JeremyKun A bit late, but for me it works with Algorithm2e

Comment: Worked for me, but I needed just `\begin{minipage}` rather than `\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}`, or else the width was 0.5*0.5 the page width, rather than just 0.5.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve the same result using `algorithm2e` package and without `minipage`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{wrapfigure}[6]{L}{0.5\textwidth} %<-- Wrapfigure covers 6 lines
      \begin{algorithm}[H]                %<-- Remove float environment
        \SetCustomAlgoRuledWidth{0.45\textwidth}  %<-- For aesthetics  
        \caption{assignment algorithm}
           i $\leftarrow$ j
      \end{algorithm}
  \end{wrapfigure}
  \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: Wrapped pseudo using algorithm2e]